# Динамический массив списком блоков

Tags: c++, структуры, шаблоны-с++

Возникла проблема в реализации динамического массива списком блоков.

```
template <typename T>
Dynamic_Array {
private: 
    int size;
    T *ar;
public:
    ...
};
```

Но меня смущает, что я буду внутри выделять память уже используя динамический массив. Прошу вас идею написания. Реализацию класса я смогу написать сам, просто хотелось бы узнать как должно выглядеть в хорошем варианте класс динамического массива.

Comment: Не очень понятно, о каком списке блоков Вы говорите.

Comment: А тьфу.. Я не про список блоков отвечал, а про непрерывный кусок. @alexolut, под списком блоков имеется в виду реализация, когда ты вместо одного массива держишь массив массивов и, когда очередной кончается, добавляешь ещё один.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну это уже на `std::deque` похоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy объясните реализацию пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так же, как стандартный вектор. Оператор квадратных скобок, добавление в конец, выкидывание из конца, обработка через итераторы как стандартных контейнеров, вставка в произвольную позицию по итератору.

Рекомендую придерживаться той же стратегии как у вектора при выделении памяти: если выделенный кусок закончился, выделить в 2 раза больше, <s>если после удаления стал в 4 раза больше, чем требуется, перевыделить и взять меньший кусок (не уверен, какого размера).</s> Оказывается, вектор [не уменьшается](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1401015/178988) при удалении ([пример](https://tio.run/##pZDNDoIwDIDve4omHhwxEjx5GPIqppaKizCW/RjU@Ow44OAd20vzpf3alKzdN0TjuNGG2lgzlLr3wTF2lfixB1PoXSVE9No0YLBjb5EYfKiVENoE6FAbmYm3AFi6k8mEClAlQn0MUJaAudcvltlUb1POiDCpdHgumE3dJiXANSnkZB5OhYKhPBRzKNjthiyN2ehv5wvSXQ7Z2h2YO567j38obG@XO/5wsEPPEvMLN9MbV5sch@gMFEp8xvEL)). Хотя если делаешь свой контейнер, то можно и уменьшать.

Comment: Вроде того : Dynamic_Array(size) { array = new T[size]}
...
void add(T el) { size *= 2; array = new T[size] ...} ?

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, то вектор, как правило, сам память не отдает.  Именно поэтому появились [swap trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253173/5371004) и [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/)

Comment: Стратегия выделения памяти "про запас" может быть разная, кстати. Для сравнения: [msvc](http://rextester.com/KOPWC43005) и [gcc](http://rextester.com/YTZGUB99417).

Comment: @openspace, не надо на каждое добавление размер удваивать. Только если не хватает. И ещё надо использовать size для числа используемых элементов и capacity для числа доступных. А ещё надо при перевыделении памяти копировать старые данные.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, насколько я помню, вектор гарантирует, что не выделит более чем в 2 раза больше памяти, чем необходимо, при использовании только добавления и более чем в 4 раза при использовании добавления и удаления. Естественно, и то, и другое, если явно не задавалось capacity.

Comment: @Qwertiy что-то не помню таких ограничений для реализаций в стандарте.